# Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu returns error Uncaught TypeError: this._menu is undefined

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu defined as below:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-left">
    <div class="search-box col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-6">
        <form action="/{{ $page->formAction }}">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownSubNav" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Portfolios & collections...
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownSubNav">
                        <li>
                            @foreach ($allPortfolios as $portfolio)
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ $portfolio->href }}">{{ $portfolio->name }}</a>
                            @endforeach
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" value="{{ @$page->search }}">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
                {!! $page->map.$page->portfolioImageSelected !!}
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have checked many posts on the subject by my case is different and I am pulling my hair off to try to figure out why it is working with this [portfololio](https://www.paulgodard.com/portfolio?p=main&c=ethereal) but not with this [one](https://www.paulgodard.com/portfolio?p=main&c=ethereal&r=4).

The only difference between the 2 pages is the number of images displayed but the dropdown menu code generated is exactly the same in both pages.

Here is the html code generated by the first page where the dropdown menu works:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-left">
    <div class="search-box col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-6">
        <form action="/portfolio">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownSubNav" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Portfolios & collections...
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownSubNav">
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=bestof"> • Best Of</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=utopia"> • Utopia</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=bw"> • Black &amp; White</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=ethereal"> • Ethereal</a>
                            ...
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" value="">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
                <button id="map" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/map?c=ethereal&p=main&r=4&m=images'; return false;"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></button><button id="mainHeartButton" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/portfolio?s=cookie'; return false;"> <img id="mainHeart" src="./assets/icons/heart0.png" class="icon20" title="spacer"></button>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the second page where it is not working

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-left">
    <div class="search-box col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-6">
        <form action="/portfolio">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownSubNav" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Portfolios & collections...
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownSubNav">
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=bestof"> • Best Of</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=utopia"> • Utopia</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=bw"> • Black &amp; White</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=ethereal"> • Ethereal</a>
                            ...
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" value="">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
                <button id="map" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/map?c=ethereal&p=main&m=images'; return false;"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></button><button id="mainHeartButton" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/portfolio?s=cookie'; return false;"> <img id="mainHeart" src="./assets/icons/heart0.png" class="icon20" title="spacer"></button>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only difference that I see is the link at the bottom which is totally normal.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction to solve this.

Comment: which bootstrap version you installed ?

Comment: The latest one 5.0.2 (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js)

Comment: i compared both elements from both pages and i saw that in the second page you have an **<a href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=ethereal">** 3 times and i didnt got that part, is there any reason to have this link 3 times ? and by the way you wrap your button inside the **a tag** maybe thats why you got an error

Comment: @mmh4all I do not see the 3 instances of the link you mention above, neither where you see the <a> tag around the buttons... I looked at both source codes ofr the page working and not working.  Can you please explain where you see that?

Comment: @Paule Godard i copied both elements from both pages using the dev tools, the second one seems strange, i guess you are using an html template engine to add some logic to your page structure, check out your element with the dev tools and you will see what i mean

Comment: check out this element in the second page **input-group-prepend**

Comment: @mmh4all I am VERY confused... or I am missing something here.  I have updated my original post which the html code generated in both page.  If I compare both codes they are identical except the link at the bottom which is normal.  I got the code from view page source in Firefox Mac latest version.

Comment: the problem accur when you have a parameter in your URL https://www.paulgodard.com/portfolio?p=main&c=ethereal&r=**4**  so i think the problem doesnt have anything with the dropdown itself, i can copy the element as solution if you want to see how its looks like ?

Comment: Your list structure is invalid. List items _must_ be children of a list. Also, it's both web design convention and Bootstrap canon to put each link in a separate list item.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I noticed that if the button and dropdown target are inside a d-flex, this error occurs.
But if both are inside a "row" div this error disappears and dropdown works ok.

Additionally, the dropdown target (div or ul) has to be just after the dropdown button.

Answer (score 0):

Your Element looks like this when i copy it from the dev tools, you might check the reason for this, and i noticed the problem accur when you have **r** parameter in the url, i hope this will lead you to find a solution

```
<div class="input-group-prepend"><a href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=ethereal">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownSubNav" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Portfolios &amp; collections...
  </button>
  </a><div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownSubNav"><a href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=ethereal">
    </a><li><a href="/portfolio?p=main&amp;c=ethereal">
                      YOUR A TAGS HERE................
                    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I totally understand that if the code looks like that something will not work.  However what I do not understand is why I do see something totally different.  As I said I am on the latest version of firefox on mac, latest version of safari as well as opera... none of them show what you see. I am totally puzzled!

Comment: @PaulGodard maybe you have to clear the cache from your hosting platform

Comment: I have done that in firefox: clear cache & site data/cookies for the site... still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  It was an anchor tag which was not closed properly in the second page.  Sorry for wasting your time but thank you for your help.

Why you were seeing a different code is still a mystery!